# jQuery AJAX() method just want to send a value in a php file

Tags: jquery

i use this code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

                        $.ajax({
                              url: 'server.php',
                              type: 'POST',
                              data : {temp : '100'},
                              success: function(data) {
                                alert('Load was performed.');
                            }   
                    });

    });
```

and just want to take the value of temp at the server.php file and print it ,
what im doing is $_POST['temp']; but dont have results

Comment: Please show the code of `server.php`

Answer (score 1):

On the PHP end, you need to actually **output** that by passing it to echo:

```
echo $_POST['temp'];
```

Comment: im doing echo ..just like u wrote it down..but as i guess the value dont "stays" in the php file...i guess this is ajax ...send  some data to perform some operation the php file and then the data are back..

so i cant print the value...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

                    $.ajax({
                          url: 'server.php',
                          type: 'POST',
                          data : "temp=100",
                          success: function(data) {
                            alert('Load was performed.');
                        }   
                });

});
```